# Could a question about live performance software be treated as appropriate?

Tags: discussion, software

Could a question that regards to music software or sequencers be treated as appropriate?

Like 'How to make this and that in Reason 4'?

Comment: This also has some implications for whether music recording is on-topic here.  Refer to http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/6/adding-recording-to-the-topics, specifically Lennart Regebro's answer.

Answer (score 13):

## Yes

Synthesizers and sequencers are just a type of musical instruments, and is without a doubt a form of musical "practice & performance, composition, technique, theory, and history."

As such it is without a shadow of a doubt on topic with the current definition of topics. The only way it could not be is if we add a "unless you use a computer" at the end. :-)

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting, I didn't think of it that way.  I am forced to upvote :P

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for the [Audio Recording and Production](http://audio.stackexchange.com/) site.

For instance, [their FAQ](http://audio.stackexchange.com/faq) has some of these topics:

> - audio editing, mixing, and mastering
> - signal processing
> - audio post-production
> - audio-related media and file formats
> - installation, configuration, and operation of software related to these
>     topics

Though, I could be wrong in over looking something, and although someone might be able to read more specific detail into what you mean, given the information provided I certainly can't and can only say, no.

Comment: *Comments Removed* -- Please let's refrain from carrying on extended conversations in comments. Comments should generally address *improvements* to the post. They're not for participating in on-going debate or parenthetical discussions. Please feel free to use the chat room or other forum to conduct such discussions. Thanks.

Comment: -1 Using software synths is not on topic on audio.SE so that sort of question would be off topic there.

Comment: -1 Their FAQ doesn't mention synthesizers and sequencers, so you overlooked something. :)